# ProjectItem.Object is null in some cases, cannot run custom tool

Tags: c#, visual-studio-extensions

I created a VSIX project to run T4 templates on build time.

Now a few cases are surfacing where this does not work. When debugging I noticed that the `ProjectItem.Object` property is `null`, so the cast to the `VSProjectItem` does not work and no custom tools are executed.

```
public void ExecuteTemplate(ProjectItem template)
{
    var ignoredTemplates = Settings.Default.IgnoreList;

    //This cast fails because template.Object property is NULL
    VSProjectItem templateVsProjectItem = (VSProjectItem)template.Object;

    if (templateVsProjectItem != null)
    {
        if (ignoredTemplates != null && ignoredTemplates.Count > 0)
        {
            if (!ignoredTemplates.Contains(templateVsProjectItem.ProjectItem.Name))
            {
                templateVsProjectItem.RunCustomTool();
            }
            else
            {
                templateVsProjectItem.RunCustomTool();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (!template.IsOpen)
            {
                var window = template.Open();
                template.Save();
                window.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                template.Save();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What could possible be the cause of this?

Comment: Is solution or project opened in visual studio?

Comment: Following vik, what are the conditions under which You run the T4 generation? Solution/project all open and loaded? Sometimes it takes time to load whole solution, you should be working with projects only once they are loaded.

Comment: Templates are .tt files with custom tool set to TextTemplatingFileGenerator' and build action set to 'None'. 'template' is never null, it never fails to fetch all .tt files, just the .Object property on those is NULL in 1 out of 10 solutions where I tried to use the extension.

Comment: I noticed that this happens when .tt files are located outside project folders (shared solution folder for example), in that case the files are not actual ProjectItems. Is there a way to still do this?

Comment: According to doc, the [ProjectItem API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte.projectitem?view=visualstudiosdk-2017) represents an item in a project. It has a difference from the item in a solution but outside the project. We do have some approach like [this](https://blog.agchapman.com/creating-solution-items-from-vs-extension/) to manage 'solution Item', but I think it won't meet your needs.